# Web Service Method Can't return a DataTable?

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy, asmx

Here's the Web Service Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("m_Token", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
public DataTable GetUserProfile()
```

Here's the line of code I use to call this method:

```
DataTable DT = (DataTable) m_ServerApp.GetUserProfile();
```

Here's the error which the compiler throws:

Cannot convert type
'WSAClient.ServerApp.GetUserProfileResponseGetUser ProfileResult' to
'System.Data.DataTable'

What is the problem? Thanks..

Comment: What versions of which API's ? This ought to work with old-school asmx WebServices, not so easily with WCF.

Comment: well, i think exception is quite self explaining - types don't match. Another thing is, that in my opinion it is bad practice to return data table as web service method result, because it is hardly understandable for non .net systems, i would go for own more specific data structure.

Comment: Show us the Structure of ProfileResult.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your client proxy method is returning an object of type `WSAClient.ServerApp.GetUserProfileResponse.GetUserProfileResult`. You will probably find that this type contains your `DataTable`.

I agree that you should not return types that are specific to .NET. A Java client will not understand what a `System.Data.DataTable` is, any more than a .NET client will understand a Java `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the Soap standards if your webservice is being used by java client then it will not be able to consume your web service. Its better you return an XML which is again a soap standard and on client side you can read this xml in dataset and can use datatable of dataset